# How can i split array into two array based on integer value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an example array I want to split:

```
(1428,217,1428)
```

How do I split it in 2 array like this?

```
(1428,1428)
(217)
```

I have tried following way but it's only return 1428 array.

```
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($value) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$value] > 1;

});
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to separate duplicate numbers in a different array? It will only return 1428 since `array_count_values` returns an array with values as keys and their frequency as value therefore **$counts** will be equal to `array('1428' => 2, '217' => 1);`. In your filter you are only returning the value if its frequency is bigger than 1, which only 1428 has a frequency bigger than 1 hence returning 1428 only.  You need to explain what you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this for your example data is to sort the array and use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get the first element of the array and store that in an array.

```
$a = [1428,217,1428];
sort($a);
$b = [array_shift($a)];

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1428
    [1] => 1428
)
Array
(
    [0] => 217
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$array = array(1428,217,1428);
$array1 = array_slice($array, 0, 2);
$array2 = array_slice($array, 2, 3);
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

And the output will like this:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1428
    [1] => 217
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1428
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will only return 1428 since `array_count_values` returns an array with values as keys and their frequency as array value therefore **$counts** will be equal to `array('1428' => 2, '217' => 1);`

If I understood your question well you should do something like this:

```
$array1 = [1428, 217, 1428];
$result = [];
foreach($array1 as $value){
  $result[$value][] = $value;  
}
```

This will not create an array for each different value but will create a new element for each unique value in `$result`.  The final value of `$result` will be `array('1428' => [1428, 1428], '217' => [217])` . Which can be easily manipulated as if they were 2 different arrays.

Let me know if this works for you, if not I will try to update my answer according to your specification.